# JavaFX BorderPane Maximising Window Issues

Tags: javafx, borderpane

My code creates a window and lays it out exactly how I want... initially. However, if I maximise the window, the top and bottom parts of the border pane do not remain in the centre. They drift off to the top left and bottom left corners.

I tried to disable the maximise window option, but again it messes up the look of the page, with the top and bottom parts moving.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage startWindow) {
    startWindow.setTitle("QuizApp");

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setTop(addHorizontalBoxWithMessage());
    borderPane.setCenter(addImageView());
    borderPane.setBottom(addHorizontalBoxWithButton());

    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 750, 663);
    startWindow.setScene(scene);

    scene.getStylesheets().add(StartWindow.class.getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

    // startWindow.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);

    startWindow.show();
}

public HBox addHorizontalBoxWithMessage() {
    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.setId("hBox");
    hBox.setMinWidth(750);
    hBox.setMinHeight(50);
    hBox.setMaxWidth(750);
    hBox.setMaxHeight(50);
    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));
    hBox.setSpacing(10);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Text message = new Text("Welcome to the QuizApp!");
    message.setId("message");

    hBox.getChildren().add(message);

    return hBox;
}

public ImageView addImageView() {
    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("quiz.jpg"));

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    imageView.setImage(image);
    imageView.setFitWidth(750);
    imageView.setFitHeight(563);

    return imageView;
}

public HBox addHorizontalBoxWithButton() {
    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.setId("hBox");
    hBox.setMinWidth(750);
    hBox.setMinHeight(50);
    hBox.setMaxWidth(750);
    hBox.setMaxHeight(50);
    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    hBox.setSpacing(10);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Button registerButton = new Button("Register");
    registerButton.setPrefSize(100, 30);
    Button loginButton = new Button("Login");
    loginButton.setPrefSize(100, 30);

    hBox.getChildren().add(registerButton);
    hBox.getChildren().add(loginButton);

    return hBox;
}
```

I only started teaching myself JavaFX last night but can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong, or find a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code replace : hBox.setMaxWidth(750);

with:
hBox.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);

The problem was that after resizing your hbox, the width was still 750 px long

Another easy option is to use JavaFX Scene Builder to figure out how GUI components works.